# When to use Cached Network Image

Tags: flutter

I have a lot images on my app, should i use it on every image?
Is there a limit to how many i can save on cache?
How the cache work here is it like cache in server, until now i didn't use local storage or cache and i think it is a waste no to use that but i don't know which situations are the best and what is the limit for this not causing memory leak.
Some of my data is live and some can be static but i show it depends on the date so should i make api call every time i switch date or store it on cache.